# How to upload a file and create a link in another library using SPServices?

Tags: web-services, file-upload, spservices

How do I upload a document (PDF) to a library and create a link to it in another library?

I need to do this using SPServices specifically..

Comment: Do you mean web services generally, or specifically the SPServices jQuery library?

Comment: Specifically the SPServices jQuery library.

Comment: what Sharepoint version are you on?

Comment: Sorry, missed that.  It's SP 2007.

Answer (score 1):

The big point here is that to upload a file via the web service, you must convert it to a stream and send it through the web service. That conversion and streaming can (depending on the file size) take a significant amount of client side resources, since it's all being processed with JavaScript. This is far less efficient than say the HTTP upload mechanism that the out of the box SharePoint forms use. This is one of those examples of a solution that you "can" do, but possibly shouldn't.

Could you give us a better overview of the problem you're trying to solve with the solution?

Comment: The problem is that the user wants the document to be uploaded to two libraries.  I'm trying to minimize it by putting it in one lib and creating a link to it in another lib.